# Why does this class object declaration work?

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I have a class

```
class Test{
  public:
    int x;
    Test(const Test& obj){x=obj.x;}
};
```

Why does

```
Test object_name(Test random_name);
```

run and does not need another object as a parameter?.
.Something like `Test random_name(Test another_random(...))`, making it a never ending way of declaring the object?

Comment: `Test object_name(Test random_name); ` is a function declaration, it doesn't "run".

Comment: OP is right, it [compiles and runs on g++](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b81106b5e8a8177a), even with `Test object_name(Test random_name (Test another_random_name (Test new_identifier)));`

Comment: I meant why does this program not give a compilation error ?. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: It isn't an error. It's a valid function declaration. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It is not an object creation, you have declared a function in `int main()` function

Comment: I'm agreeing with P.W. that this looks like a variation on the recurrent "most vexing parse" type of question…

Comment: The compiler is generating a default constructor for you, so the second creation takes no parameters.

Comment: When we define our own constructor then compiler does not define a default constructor.So this should not be a good explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line:

```
Test object_name(Test random_name);
```

declares a function called `object_name` that takes a `Test` as a paramter and returns a `Test`.  It does not declare an object.  It is perfectly legal to declare a function like this inside another function, it's just implicitly `extern`.

Comment: My main function looks like
int main() {
 Test Object_name(Test random_name);
 return 0;
}
I want to ask,why is this not an error?.The object in brackets should ideally require another object and this should go on.

Comment: Also note: the compiler accepts the declaration fine, but any attempt to use `object_name` make this fact obvious. Example error: "main.cpp:15:25: error: request for member ‘x’ in ‘object_name’, which is of non-class type ‘Test(Test)’".

Comment: @ViditVirmani:  There are no objects here -- just an extern function declaration for a function that is never called.  If you tried to call it, you'd get a link error, but as you've described, no error.

Comment: @ViditVirmani You are declaring a function in `int main()` function

Answer (score 6):

Substitute `Test` with a PoD like `int` and you will see what is happening

```
Test object_name(Test random_name); //1

int object_name(int random_name); //2
```

You can see that the second statement is a function declaration which takes an `int` as argument and returns an `int`.

This is due to a well-known rule in CPP related to ambiguity resolution.
From the CPP working draft (N4713):

> **9.8 Ambiguity resolution [stmt.ambig]**
>
> 1 There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements and declarations: *An expression-statement with a function-style explicit type conversion  as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts with a (.* **In those cases the statement is a declaration**.
>
> 2 [ Note: *If the statement cannot syntactically be a declaration, there is no ambiguity, so this rule does not apply*. The whole statement might need to be examined to determine whether this is the case.

Comment: I'm a fan of this answer. It very clearly shows where one's misconception may lie.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refactored version that should help explain what's going on. I've added another constructor to illustrate what's going on.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test{
  public:
    int x = 27;
    Test(const int y) : x(y) { cout << "ctor-1" << endl; }
    ~Test() {}
    Test(const Test& obj) : x(obj.x) { cout << "ctor-2" << endl; }
    operator int() const { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Creating function declaration" << endl;
    Test object_name(Test random_name);

    // This works fine
    cout << "Creating alpha" << endl;
    Test alpha(4);
    cout << "Calling `object_name`" << endl;
    cout << object_name(alpha) << endl;

    // This fails because object_name is a function.
    // cout << object_name.x << endl;
    return 0;
}

Test object_name(Test random_name)
{
    cout << "Creating another Test within `object_name`." << endl;
    return Test(random_name.x + 13);
}
```

Here, we see that the first constructor is invoked twice: once for `alpha` and again within `object_name`. The second constructor is invoked when we call `object_name`, which accepts a parameter passed by value.

### Output

```
Creating function declaration
Creating alpha
ctor-1
Calling `object_name`
ctor-2
Creating another Test within `object_name`.
ctor-1
17
```